# Update only selected Fields and not all the columns in database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am working on a project using Struts2. There are columns such as `eid`, `age`, `city`, `name` and `gender`. I want to update only `age` and `city` but I'm required to pass `gender` and `name` also as a hidden field because object is repopulating and I want to populate those field what ever I want to update.

```
<s:textfield name="age" label="Age" value="%{emp.age}"/>
<s:textfield name="city" label="City" value="%{emp.city}"/>
<s:hidden name="eid" value="%{emp.eid}"/>
<s:hidden name="gender" value="%{emp.gender}"/>
<s:hidden name="name" value="%{emp.name}"/>
```

and my query is

```
update EmpInfo set Name=?, Password=?, Gender=?, City=?, Age=?, Date=? where Emp_Id=?
```

I don't want to use hidden fields in jsp. How to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. If you don't want to update name and gender, then don't have them in the query: `update EmpInfo set Password=?, City=?, Age=?, Date=? where Emp_Id=?`

Comment: i can not change query. because i am using more then one place for example if i want to change only age or name or gender according to requirement for all i am using same query.

Comment: Then read the values from the database and update them with the values they already have. Or don't change this query, but write another one.

Comment: If your object is being populated by a select query after the update happens, then you don't need to pass gender and name in hidden fields and you don't have to include those fields in your query.  As @JBNizet said, if you have to update other fields somewhere else, write another query for that situation.